# Reading from a file to a array of structures using a function in C

Tags: c

I am attempting to allocate and fread information from a file into an array of structures within a function. The data is stored with a long which is the number of entries followed by keys for each entry each of which is 32 characters long.

I have managed to do this not in a function using the code

```
FILE *fr=NULL;
fr = fopen (TRANS_FILE, "rb");
long n_total_c=0;
object_dict* cKey;
fread(&n_total_c, sizeof(long), 1, fr);
cKey=  malloc (n_total_c*sizeof(object_dict));
int ii=0;
for(ii=0;ii<n_total_c;ii++){
  fread(&cKey[ii], sizeof(object_dict)-1, 1, fr);
  cKey[ii][33] = "\0";
}

typedef char object_dict[33];
```

However when I move it into a function I can allocate the memory correctly, but reading the data into the array causes a seg fault.

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong in the fread?

```
int openDict(){
    FILE *fr=NULL;
    fr = fopen (TRANS_FILE, "rb");
    long n_total_c=0;
    object_dict* cKey;
    get_Tokens(&n_total_c,&cKey,fr);
}


void get_Tokens(long* n_total, object_dict** storage_array,FILE* inputfile){
    *storage_array=NULL;
    size_t read_info=0;
    read_info = fread(&n_total, sizeof(long), 1, inputfile);
    *storage_array =  malloc ( (*n_total) * sizeof(object_dict));

    int ii=0;
    for(ii=0;ii<*n_total;ii++){
        fread((*storage_array)[ii], sizeof(object_dict)-1, 1, inputfile);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: why you are passing as &n_total do pass as like n_total -because it contains &n_total_c

Comment: yes pass `n_total_c` in the default way, it is a primitive data type

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
read_info = fread(n_total, sizeof(long), 1, input file);
```

instead of

```
read_info = fread(&n_total, sizeof(long), 1, inputfile);
```